# BarChart does not display asymmetric error bars correctly

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, charts, around

BarChart seems to read the uncertainty in elements the other way around. The object:

Around[5, {1, 10}]

is evaluated as [image].

However, when you use it in a BarChart, the uncertainties are swapped:

```
BarChart[{Around[5, {1, 10}]}]
```

plots:

[image]

This does not happen with other functions such as ListPlot:

```
ListPlot[{Around[5, {1, 10}]}]
```

[image]

I guess this is a bug, but just wanted to make sure.

Version: 12.1.1.0
Platform: MacOS 10.13.6

Comment: I get the same and this is not what I expected either.